# Uncaught Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render. Table with dynamic columns

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am creating a table which shows the exam times. This table has fixed rows (Exam Times) but the number of columns change according to the number of unique exam dates. For example, if we have 3 courses with dates "11/2/23", "12/2/23" and "11/2/23", we will have 2 columns: "11/2/23" and "12/2/23". The first and third courses go to their corresponding cell in the "11/2/23" column and the same thing happens for the other course.
Everything is working well until I add a new lesson which has an exam date not in the columns. I get these warning and errors:

```
Warning: React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by TimeRow. This will lead to bugs and errors if not fixed. For more information, read the Rules of Hooks: https://reactjs.org/link/rules-of-hooks

   Previous render            Next render
   ------------------------------------------------------
1. useState                   useState
2. useState                   useState
3. useState                   useState
4. useState                   useState
5. useState                   useState
6. useState                   useState
7. useState                   useState
8. useState                   useState
9. undefined                  useState
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    at TimeRow (http://localhost:5173/src/components/Charts/TimeRow.jsx?t=1698863431873:117:3)
    at tbody
    at table
    at Table (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-LLGW6U6E.js?v=0ad6b014:11854:29)
    at ExamChart (http://localhost:5173/src/components/Charts/ExamChart.jsx?t=1698933300753:35:7)
    at div
    at div
    at div
    at CardBody (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-LLGW6U6E.js?v=0ad6b014:7018:29)
    at div
    at Card (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-LLGW6U6E.js?v=0ad6b014:6677:29)
    at div
    at Col (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-LLGW6U6E.js?v=0ad6b014:705:29)
    at div
    at Row (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-LLGW6U6E.js?v=0ad6b014:552:29)
    at UserPage (http://localhost:5173/src/views/UserPage/UserPage.jsx?t=1698933156534:42:7)
    at RenderedRoute (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-router-dom.js?v=0ad6b014:3133:5)
    at Routes (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-router-dom.js?v=0ad6b014:3542:5)
    at div
    at div
    at div
    at Admin (http://localhost:5173/src/views/Admin.jsx?t=1698933156534:33:7)
    at PrivatRoute (http://localhost:5173/src/global/functions.jsx:20:3)
    at RenderedRoute (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-router-dom.js?v=0ad6b014:3133:5)
    at Routes (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-router-dom.js?v=0ad6b014:3542:5)
    at Router (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-router-dom.js?v=0ad6b014:3489:15)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-router-dom.js?v=0ad6b014:3938:5)
    at ContextInfo (http://localhost:5173/src/contexts/InfoContext.jsx:26:27)
    at BackgroundColorWrapper (http://localhost:5173/src/components/BackgroundColorWrapper/BackgroundColorWrapper.jsx:21:29)
    at ThemeContextWrapper (http://localhost:5173/src/components/ThemeWrapper/ThemeWrapper.jsx:21:29)
    at App (http://localhost:5173/src/App.jsx?t=1698933156534:52:39)
```

```
Uncaught Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.
    at updateWorkInProgressHook (react-dom.development.js:16507:13)
    at updateReducer (react-dom.development.js:16568:14)
    at updateState (react-dom.development.js:17004:10)
    at Object.useState (react-dom.development.js:17915:16)
    at useState (react.development.js:1622:21)
    at DayPeriod (TimeRow.jsx:15:45)
    at TimeRow.jsx:104:18
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at TimeRow (TimeRow.jsx:101:34)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:18)
6console.js:213 The above error occurred in the <TimeRow> component:

    at TimeRow (http://localhost:5173/src/components/Charts/TimeRow.jsx?t=1698863431873:117:3)
    at tbody
    at table
    at Table (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-LLGW6U6E.js?v=0ad6b014:11854:29)
    at ExamChart (http://localhost:5173/src/components/Charts/ExamChart.jsx?t=1698933593217:34:7)
    at div
    at div
    at div
    at CardBody (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-LLGW6U6E.js?v=0ad6b014:7018:29)
    at div
    at Card (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-LLGW6U6E.js?v=0ad6b014:6677:29)
    at div
    at Col (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-LLGW6U6E.js?v=0ad6b014:705:29)
    at div
    at Row (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/chunk-LLGW6U6E.js?v=0ad6b014:552:29)
    at UserPage (http://localhost:5173/src/views/UserPage/UserPage.jsx?t=1698933156534:42:7)
    at RenderedRoute (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-router-dom.js?v=0ad6b014:3133:5)
    at Routes (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-router-dom.js?v=0ad6b014:3542:5)
    at div
    at div
    at div
    at Admin (http://localhost:5173/src/views/Admin.jsx?t=1698933156534:33:7)
    at PrivatRoute (http://localhost:5173/src/global/functions.jsx:20:3)
    at RenderedRoute (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-router-dom.js?v=0ad6b014:3133:5)
    at Routes (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-router-dom.js?v=0ad6b014:3542:5)
    at Router (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-router-dom.js?v=0ad6b014:3489:15)
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/react-router-dom.js?v=0ad6b014:3938:5)
    at ContextInfo (http://localhost:5173/src/contexts/InfoContext.jsx:26:27)
    at BackgroundColorWrapper (http://localhost:5173/src/components/BackgroundColorWrapper/BackgroundColorWrapper.jsx:21:29)
    at ThemeContextWrapper (http://localhost:5173/src/components/ThemeWrapper/ThemeWrapper.jsx:21:29)
    at App (http://localhost:5173/src/App.jsx?t=1698933156534:52:39)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
overrideMethod @ console.js:213
react-dom.development.js:26923 Uncaught Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.
    at updateWorkInProgressHook (react-dom.development.js:16507:13)
    at updateReducer (react-dom.development.js:16568:14)
    at updateState (react-dom.development.js:17004:10)
    at Object.useState (react-dom.development.js:17915:16)
    at useState (react.development.js:1622:21)
    at DayPeriod (TimeRow.jsx:15:45)
    at TimeRow.jsx:104:18
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at TimeRow (TimeRow.jsx:101:34)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:18)
```

This is my ExamChart.jsx:

```
import React from "react";
import { useMemo } from 'react';
import { useInfo } from "../../contexts/InfoContext";
import "../../assets/css/nucleo-icons.css";
import TimeRow from './TimeRow';
import {
  Table
} from "reactstrap";

import "./ExamChart.css"
import { mapTimeToIndex } from "../../Functions/mapTimeToIndex";
import { uniquifyArrayByKey } from "../../Functions/uniquifyArrayByKey";

export default function ExamChart() {
  // Token
  const tokenJson = localStorage.getItem("authTokens");
  const tokenClass = JSON.parse(tokenJson);
  const token = tokenClass.token.access;

  // Info
  const { info, changeInfo } = useInfo();

  let [ExamTable, setExamTable] = React.useState([]);
  let [ExamDates, setExamDates] = React.useState([]);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const courses = info.courseChoosed.map(course => new Course(course));
    setExamTable(courses);
    ExamTable = uniquifyArrayByKey(ExamTable, "complete_course_number")   // Uniquify
    // setExamTable(uniquifyArrayByKey(ExamTable, "complete_course_number"));
    let ExamTimes = courses.map(course => course.exam_times[0].date);
    ExamTimes = ExamTimes.map((item) => item.substring(item.length - 8)); // Remove Indexes appearing at the beginning of the dates
    ExamTimes = [...new Set(ExamTimes)];                                  // Uniquify
    ExamTimes = ExamTimes.sort();                                         // Sort
    setExamDates(ExamTimes)
    console.log ("Exam time is: " + ExamTimes);
  }, [info.courseChoosed]);

  class Course {
    constructor(props) {
      this.name = props.name;
      this.complete_course_number = props.complete_course_number;
      this.class_gp = props.class_gp;
      this.course_times = props.course_times;
      this.base_course_number = parseInt(this.complete_course_number.substring(0, this.complete_course_number.length - 3));
      this.exam_times = props.exam_times;
    }
  }

  const keyedExamTable = useMemo(() => {                             // Mapping the courses into keyedExamTable
    const numSections = ExamDates.length;
    const emptySection = () => ({
      0: null,
      1: null,
      2: null,
      3: null,
      4: null,
      5: null
    });
    const emptyTime = (numSections) => {
      const sections = {};
      for (let i = 0; i < numSections; i++) {
        sections[i] = emptySection();
      }
      return sections;
    };

    let NumInEachSlot = [];
    let Rows = 6, Cols = numSections;
    for (let i = 0; i < Rows; i++) {
      NumInEachSlot[i] = Array(Cols).fill(0);
    }

    return ExamTable.reduce(
      (lessonsKeyedByDayAndPeriod, currentPeriod) => {
        
        try
        {
          let ExamTime = currentPeriod.exam_times[0].exam_start_time;
          let ExamDay = currentPeriod.exam_times[0].date;
        }
        catch 
        {
          return lessonsKeyedByDayAndPeriod;
        }

        let ExamTime = currentPeriod.exam_times[0].exam_start_time;
        let ExamDay = currentPeriod.exam_times[0].date;
        
        let time = mapTimeToIndex(ExamTime, true);
        // let day = MapDateToIndex(ExamDay, ExamDates);
        let day = ExamDates.findIndex(day => ExamDay.includes(day));
        console.log("Mapped date is: " + day);
        try
        {
          NumInEachSlot[time][day] ++;
        }
        catch 
        {
          return lessonsKeyedByDayAndPeriod;
        }

        NumInEachSlot[time][day] ++;
        let count = NumInEachSlot[time][day];
        try {
          lessonsKeyedByDayAndPeriod[time][day][count] = currentPeriod;
        }
        catch (error) {
          // console.log("ERROR is: " + error);
        }
        return lessonsKeyedByDayAndPeriod
      },
      {
        0: emptyTime(numSections),
        1: emptyTime(numSections),
        2: emptyTime(numSections),
        3: emptyTime(numSections),
        4: emptyTime(numSections),
        5: emptyTime(numSections),
      }
    )
  }, [ExamDates, ExamTable])

  return (
    <>
      <Table className="ExamsTable">
        <thead className="text-primary TableHead">
          <tr>
            <th className="table-head text-center "></th>
            {
              Object.entries(ExamDates).map( (entry) => {
                return (
                  <th className="table-head text-center ">{entry.toString().substring(2)}</th>
                )
              })
            }
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody className="ExamChartTableBody">
          <TimeRow ExamT="8-10"  periods={keyedExamTable[0]} />
          <TimeRow ExamT="10-12" periods={keyedExamTable[1]} />
          <TimeRow ExamT="12-14" periods={keyedExamTable[2]} />
          <TimeRow ExamT="14-16" periods={keyedExamTable[3]} />
          <TimeRow ExamT="16-18" periods={keyedExamTable[4]} />
          <TimeRow ExamT="18-20" periods={keyedExamTable[5]} />
        </tbody>
      </Table>
    </>
  );
}
```

And this is my TimeRow.jsx:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import "./ExamChart.css"
import {timeStringToFloat} from "../../Functions/timeStringToFloat"

function DayPeriod (Input) {
  return (
    <div>
      {Object.entries(Input).map(([count, entry]) => {
        return (
          <div className="ExamListContainer">
            {entry !== null && (
              <div key={entry.complete_course_number}>
                <div  className="ExamContainer">
                    <div 
                      id = {entry.complete_course_number}
                      className="exam text-center"}
                    >
                        <div>
                          <strong title= {entry.name}>
                          </strong>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  )
}

const TimeRow = ({ periods, ExamT }) => {
    return (
    <>
        <tr className="TableROW">
        <td className="ExamsTable_column text-center" style = {{fontSize : "x-small"}}>{ExamT}</td>
        {Object.entries(periods).map(([time, entry]) => {
            return (
            <td className="ExamsTable_column2" key={time}>
                {DayPeriod(entry)}
            </td>
            )
        })}
        </tr>
    </>
    );
};
export default TimeRow;
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!